# How to filter tag/product_collection resource model by tag name in magento

Tags: php, magento, model

i want to **filter tag/product_collection resource model by tag name.**

for that i have written below's code

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('tag/product_collection');
$collection->addFieldToFilter("name",array('like'=>'%dixit%'));
print_r($collection->getData());
```

**Then it shows just null array.**

if i will comment

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter("name",array('like'=>'%dixit%'));
```

**this line then its shows below's output**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [entity_id] => 323 [entity_type_id] => 4 [attribute_set_id] => 4 [type_id] => simple [sku] => 8018-90 [has_options] => 0 [required_options] => 0 [created_at] => 2010-03-11 12:17:46 [updated_at] => 2013-07-24 12:12:56 [product_id] => 323 [item_store_id] => 1 [tag_id] => 1 [name] => dixit [tag_status] => 0 [tag_name] => dixit ) )
```

So how to filter using like query this model.

**i have try both filter attribute way**

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter("name",array('like'=>'%dixit%'));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter("name",array('like'=>'%dixit%'));
```

But none of them working.

Comment: sorry i am a bit confused, are you expecting more that the result you are getting? cause the code itself is correct.

Comment: i need to execute like query for product tag which have '%keyword%' pattern. no of result is not matter. i just want all which have this like keyword. and code is working for listing all keyword but i need to add filter parameter so only matched keywords are comes in result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $collection->getSelect()->Where(' name like ?',"% dixit %");
```

Using this way you can filter tag_name as requirement.

getSelect() method get select query and we just append where query to select query using where methods.

its simple method.
i have check its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Hello check below code may be help you

```
 $tagName='dixit';
$tagId= Mage::getModel('tag/tag')->loadByName($tagName)->getId();
$tagId = 3;  
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('tag/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addTagFilter($tagId);

print_r($products->getData());
```

Comment: this working fine but i need product_id in select query so there are any way. you are near the answer but need more parameter in selected column like tag/product_collection. can you have ?

Comment: you have any suggestion with tag/product_collection model ?